# Computer Display pixel and Image pixel

Tags: image-processing

I saw two identical images on a webpage of same size, one with good reolution and other with lesser reolution (like blurred image when it gets zoomed). When I used Measureit (firefox plugin) tool to measure the pixel count of the images, I was suprised to see both images are being shown same pixel count like 280*700.

I thought that image with a fine resolution would show more pixel count than the other one.

Question-1: I'm bit confused here. Am I measuring the pixel count of the image in the webpage or am I measuring the pixel count of my computer display?

Question-2: If I have to count the pixel counts of the image itself what tool should I use? Or can I use java like language to count the pixel count of an image.

Answer (score 1):

Question-1:
After trying it out, I believe you are measuring the pixel count of the image in the webpage because you are using a firefox plugin. Even zooming in and out does not change the element I was measuring. The search bar was still 296 width whether in normal or zoomed in at 150%.

Question-2:
You can also find out more information of the image if you save it and check its file properties. In terms of tools, I would suggest importing it in Photoshop to get a good idea of its true size.

I hope this helps?

Comment: But if it is pixel count of image then how could a blurred image and image with fine resolution can have same pixel count?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to address that. Would you be able to include a link of the webpage?

Comment: Yes, this is the link which has different images of squirrels, out of which one is blurred. But when I measure all of them gives  280*210 pixels. http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6050-howto-compareimages.jsp

Comment: I think this links helps understand  - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/spatial_resolution.htm. This says pixel resoluition can't judge the clarity of the image but it is spatial resolution like ppi or dpi which can give the clarity of an image.

Comment: So picture A is original, and Picture B is scaled and zoomed picture. 

Since Picture B was scaled in GIMP, it was fit to have the frame of 280by210. If the creator just zoomed in and not scaled it, then the pixel count will be smaller. However, he may not have done that so that it has the same frame as the other images.

DPI will only be evident when printing and not digital. It can be hard to tell from an digital image that has 72 DPI to a similar image with 300 DPI but evident when you print both out as the 300 DPI will be better.

Comment: Okay, but can we say that if two images on a digital display is of same size(in your display) then both of them would have same pixel count, especially the images embedded the web page?

Comment: One last question, when I downloaded the image both of them are having the same properties (given below). But the image with good resolution is occupying more space, than other (both are in same format).                                                                                             Pixels - 280 * 210
Resolution - 72 dpi
Bit depth - 24
Resolution unit - 2
color representation - sRGB
Compressed bits/pixel - 4

Comment: It goes back to the zoom operation. Since it was zoomed, it only needs to remember a smaller bitmap data of the image. It is then scaled which is just using that zoomed bitmap and enlarge to the 280by210 resolution using interpolation. I dont have Gimp but I tested out in Photoshop that when I cropped the original image and scaled it to the resolution, the lowest file size I can save is 37kb. This supports it and Photoshop may have include some metadata compared to Gimp hehe. Hope I have been helpful.